# Create custom invoice using default pdf with additional option in admin to download

Tags: custom, invoice, pdf

I need to create a custom invoice using the default pdf class having an additional option in admin/orders download as "Invoice with vat"
I did create a module using code from the following link, now I need to link it up with an admin download option.
[Module](https://meetanshi.com/blog/override-magento-2-invoice-pdf/)

Im new in magento so need detailed solution please.